# How is the p value calculated for multiple variables in linear regression?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, data-science

[image]

I am wondering how the p value is calculated for various variables in a multiple linear regression. I am sure upon reading several resources that <5% indicates the variable is significant for the model. But how is the p value calculated for each and every variable in the multiple linear regression?

I tried to see the statsmodels summary using the summary() function. I can just see the values. I didn't find any resource on how p value for various variables in a multiple linear regression is calculated.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit() 
print(results.summary())
```

This question has no error but requires an intuition on how p value is calculated for various variables in a multiple linear regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inferential statistics work by comparison to known distributions. In the case of regression, that distribution is typically the [t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)

You'll notice that each variable has an estimated coefficient from which an associated t-statistic is calculated. `x1` for example, has a t-value of `-0.278`. To get the p-value, we take that t-value, place it on the t-distribution, and calculate the probability of getting a value as extreme as the t-value you calculated. You can gain some intuition for this by noticing that the p-value column is called `P>|t|`

An additional wrinkle here is that the exact shape of the t-distribution depends on the degrees of freedom

So to calculate a p-value, you need 2 pieces of information: the t-statistic and the residual degrees of freedom of your model (97 in your case)

Taking `x1` as an example, you can calculate the p-value in Python like this:

```
import scipy.stats
scipy.stats.t.sf(abs(-0.278), df=97)*2

0.78160405761659357
```

The same is done for each of the other predictors using their respective t-values

Comment: can you please elaborate on how t value is calculated?

Comment: can you please elaborate on how the t distribution is calculated?

Comment: t-value is usually calculated as coef/standard error. you usually dont need to explicitly calculate the the t-distribution yourself as packages like scipy has modules that can calculate t-values for you, but you can check how the pdf of the t-distribution is calculated in the linked wiki page